Why are these Clow Cards under the Light Card?
Hmmmm..... Aside the Shadow Card and the Glow Card, why are these Clow Cards (on the list below) under the Light Card?
List:

Big Card
Create Card
Little Card
Return Card
Sweet Card

https://ccsakura.fandom.com/wiki/Clow_Cards
I can definitely see and understand how the Glow Card is related to the Light Card seeing how Light glows in the dark and the resource does explain why the Shadow Card is under the Light Card, but do the rest have some connection with the Light Card compared to the Glow Card and the Shadow Card?
Are there any significant reasons? 
